# Removing duplicates, conditional on a value within a column

Tags: r, duplicates, data.table, conditional-statements

I have a data set which is partly panel data and partly cross section.

```
 DT <- fread(
    "Val panelID C   D  E   F   iso   year   
    1   A     NA  1  NA  NA  NLD   1998
    1   A     NA  1  NA  NA  NLD   1998
    1   B     NA  2  NA  NA  NLD   1998   
    1   B     NA  2  NA  NA  NLD   1998   
    1   C     NA  3  NA  NA  GRC   2001  
    1   C     NA  3  NA  NA  GRC   2001    
    1   D     NA  4  NA  NA  GRC   2002
    1   D     NA  4  NA  NA  GRC   2002 
    1   E     NA  7  NA  NA  NLD   1999
    1   F     1   NA  1  NA  EUR   2009   
    1   G     0   NA  2  0   EUR   2000    
    1   H     0   NA  2  0   EUR   2001    
    1   I     0   NA  3  2   GBR   2001   
    1   J     0   NA  4  NA  GBR   2002
    0   K     NA  1  NA  NA  NLD   1999
    0   L     NA  2  NA  NA  NLD   2000
    0   K     NA  1  NA  NA  NLD   1999
    0   L     NA  2  NA  NA  NLD   2000   
    0   M     NA  3  NA  NA  GRC   2001   
    0   N     NA  4  NA  NA  GRC   2002 
    0   O     NA  7  NA  NA  NLD   1999
    0   O     NA  7  NA  NA  NLD   1999
    0   P     1   NA  1  NA  EUR   2009   
    0   Q     0   NA  2  0   EUR   2000    
    0   R     0   NA  2  0   EUR   2001    
    0   Q     0   NA  2  0   EUR   2000    
    0   R     0   NA  2  0   EUR   2001 
    0   S     0   NA  3  2   GBR   2001   
    0   T     0   NA  4  NA  GBR   2002",
    header = TRUE
)
```

For the `iso` code `NLD`, somehow values got duplicated. The other values are fine! So I would like to write code that only for `iso=="NLD` removes the columns where `panelID` is duplicated. I have tried:

```
DT[iso=="NLD", unique(DT, by = "panelID")]
```

But that somehow removes way more than what I want.

Desired output:

```
 DT <- fread(
    "Val name  C   D  E   F   iso   year   
    1   A     NA  1  NA  NA  NLD   1998
    1   B     NA  2  NA  NA  NLD   1998   
    1   C     NA  3  NA  NA  GRC   2001  
    1   C     NA  3  NA  NA  GRC   2001    
    1   D     NA  4  NA  NA  GRC   2002
    1   D     NA  4  NA  NA  GRC   2002 
    1   E     NA  7  NA  NA  NLD   1999
    1   F     1   NA  1  NA  EUR   2009   
    1   G     0   NA  2  0   EUR   2000    
    1   H     0   NA  2  0   EUR   2001    
    1   I     0   NA  3  2   GBR   2001   
    1   J     0   NA  4  NA  GBR   2002
    0   K     NA  1  NA  NA  NLD   1999
    0   L     NA  2  NA  NA  NLD   2000  
    0   M     NA  3  NA  NA  GRC   2001   
    0   N     NA  4  NA  NA  GRC   2002 
    0   O     NA  7  NA  NA  NLD   1999
    0   P     1   NA  1  NA  EUR   2009   
    0   Q     0   NA  2  0   EUR   2000    
    0   R     0   NA  2  0   EUR   2001    
    0   Q     0   NA  2  0   EUR   2000    
    0   R     0   NA  2  0   EUR   2001 
    0   S     0   NA  3  2   GBR   2001   
    0   T     0   NA  4  NA  GBR   2002",
    header = TRUE
)
```

Comment: Can't you just `unique(DT, by = c("iso", "panelID"))`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! That would remove all panel observations for the other countries as well. Only for NLD they are actually duplicates.

Comment: How do you define a duplicate? If there is no duplicates in other countries they won't be removed

Comment: If the issue is for removing duplicates, wouldn't ``DT[!duplicated(DT),]`` suffice?

Comment: some `EUR`-rows are still duplicated in your desired output... 19-21 and 20-22. Is that right?

Comment: @Wimpel That is exactly the point! And they should be. Only `iso3c==NLD` are actually duplicates. The others are panel observations.

Comment: You could do `DT[, if(iso == "NLD") unique(.SD, by = "panelID") else .SD, by = iso]` but it feels a bit silly

Comment: @DavidArenburg I understand hahaha. I would normally repair the mistake where it happened. However in this instance it's a mistake in a dataset which took about 3 weeks to impute. It worked by the way! You're a life saver, thanks!

Comment: another option is `DT[-DT[, .I[iso=="NLD" & duplicated(panelID)]]]`

Comment: Or: ``DT[!(duplicated(DT) & iso == 'NLD'),]`` for some code-colfing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving an answer with the alternatives proposed in the comments:

@DavidAremburg:

```
DT[, if(iso == "NLD") unique(.SD, by = "panelID") else .SD, by = iso]
```

This approach evaluates wether `iso == "NLD"` and returns the unique records by `panelID` if true, and the whole table if false.

@Nutle:

```
DT[!(duplicated(DT) & iso == 'NLD'),]
```

This approach filters OUT the rows that are duplicated AND for which `iso == "NLD"`.

All the credit is for the authors of the answers.